# WSO2 API Manager 2.1 upgrade to 2.6

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

We've upgraded our WSO2 API Manager from version 2.1 to 2.6. We are using all in one deployment. After migration we have a very confusing situation. In  a Store I see no published API's until I log in to the Store. Then, in a Publisher app I see all the API's in a published state, but when I edit any of them I am not able to save it or go to Implement or Manage tab - always a 'null' error appears. A stack trace from wso2carbon.log for such cases is below. I have no idea what is going wrong and any help would be very appreciated.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-07 09:27:49,622] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/publisher/modules/api/add.jag#134)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_6(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:134)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_43(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:136)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_5(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:520)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:54)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:943)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.manageAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.saveAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:1159)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updateAPIDesign(APIProviderHostObject.java:991)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 69 more
 {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag}
```

Comment: have you copied synapse-config files as given in Step 5 from https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#210)

Comment: We did such a migration and it turned to by more reliable just redeploy the APIs even having tens of API deployed. Better than spending time looking for missed configurations.

Comment: @AshwinK yep, checked twice.

Comment: @gusto2 thanks man! Thinking that way too after a week of researching..

Comment: In case of creating new API & redeploying it, you will have to add applications for each apis. Try this step as well: stop wso2, delete `solr` directory from WSO2-HOME directory. Then Rename the `<lastAccessTimeLocation>` element in the `<WSO2-HOME>/repository/conf/registry.xml` file(add some `_` or `1` at the end of tag value)

Comment: @AshwinK tryed your approach - no changes :(

Comment: @IDeveloper did you get the solution ?

Comment: @AshwinK unfortunately not yet :(

Comment: I've raised github [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/4452) regarding same.

Comment: @AshwinK any news? I've moved to 2.2 from 2.1, so far so good.

Comment: @IDeveloper didn't get any response from wso2 team yet. I also faced same problem, but at last I've recreated all the APIs & resubscribed Application to respective APIs by script I've created.

Comment: I had the same issue, I fixed by disabling the access control support for API Publisher ( <EnableAccessControl> to false ) in <APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml.